# How to enable .htaccess support for phpstorms builtin webserver

Tags: php, .htaccess

I read, that the builtin webserver of phpstorm supports .htaccess (as apache does).
I defined a .htaccess in the root directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .html index.php
```

Calling anything.html should load index.html but I get a 404-Error.

I cann´t find a config to switch the .htaccess on.
Any idea what´s going wrong?

Comment: A 404 does sound more like "file not found", not "server error because htaccess may be wrong", which would be a 503. Did you take a look at the error/access log (or even firebug > networking) to see where it is redirecting you?

Comment: The .htaccess works fine with apache.  I suppose the builtin webserver of phpstorm doesn´t use the .htaccess and therefore delivers a 404 because anything.html doesn´t exist. I´m looking for a solution how to tell the server to use the .htaccess